PyTorch C++ extension: efficiently accumulate results from threads in tensor
I am implementing a PyTorch C++ extension that employs parallellism. The desired result is a N x D matrix, and each thread computes one row of this result. What is the recommended way to accumulate these rows?


To put this into context, my code looks as follows (simplified):
at::Tensor nearestKKeys(at::Tensor queries, at::Tensor keys, int k, int maxLeafSize) {
    /*
    queries: (Nq, D)
    keys: (Nk, D)
    k: int
    return: (Nq, k)
    */
    int Nq = queries.size(0);

    at::Tensor result = at::empty({Nq, k}, at::ScalarType::Int);
    at::Tensor indices = at::arange({Nk}, keys.device())
    BallTreePtr pBallTree = buildBallTree(
        keys,
        indices,
        maxLeafSize,
        0
    );
    
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int n=0; n<Nq; n++) {
        at::Tensor query = queries.index({n});
        
        BestMatchesPtr pBestMatches = std::make_shared<BestMatches>(k);
        // places the desired result for this query in *pBestMatches
        pBallTree->query(query, query_norm, pBestMatches, k);
        
        // place the desired row in results
        at::Tensor matches = pBestMatches->getMatches();
        result.index_put_({n}, matches);
   }
}

This is currently not very efficient, and my profiler tells me that the threads spend a lot of time waiting on each other. I believe this is because of the result variable being shared between threads. I don't think that pBallTree being shared really matters (because it's a pointer), but do tell me if I'm mistaken. So, hence my question: What is the recommended way to accumulate these rows?

Allocations generally do not scale well. The thing is you perform a std::make_shared<BestMatches> for each iteration and it needs to allocate not only a BestMatches object but also a control block (the reference-counting data structure). This means at least 2 allocations per iteration.
I am not sure you actually need a shared pointer. A simple std::unique_ptr is certainly enough here since the pointer is not actually shared. In fact, I do not think you actually need dynamic allocation at all. Indeed, BestMatches can certainly be allocated on the stack once in a parallel section and reused between multiple iteration. If you need to call the constructor and there is no way to easily recycle the object, then you can recycle this memory area using a placement new (don't forget to call the destructor though).
I wonder if lines like at::Tensor matches = pBestMatches->getMatches(); also perform allocations. If at::Tensor is not a view of the tensor, then memory should be allocated and a copy is certainly done. Both operations do not scale. Can't you use views or avoid creating copies?
I assume other functions of the loops a thread safe and you did test your code carefully. Race conditions not only break the code but also tends to make the code slower.
I also assume result.index_put_ just perform a basic 1D tensor copy. If so, then accessing results is not really a problem since the default OpenMP scheduling policy tends not to cause much false sharing issue.
